# hp laptop frequently Disconnect from Hotspot

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, network-manager, hot-spot

I completely erased Windows license 2 days ago and shifted to Ubuntu 20.04.
In Ubuntu I'm facing Wi-Fi connection issue [unlike Windows 8.1 (64-bit)].

On starting laptop it goes well. But later on, Wi-Fi connection to Airtel 4G hotspot router turns off suddenly. Therefore I switch to mobile hotspot. Half the time, it works but sometimes shows connection failure. Even when mobile hotspot is connected (if there is no connection error), then after some time the mobile hotspot also shuts down.

Wireless connectivity details of laptop: 802.11b/g/n (1x1)

Comment: In a terminal window, `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` will shou you network logs.

Comment: The following is the output I noticed on putting the above command among several " <info>" command output : Aug 06 19:07:14 rkhome NetworkManager[703]: <warn>  [1596721034.4284] sup-iface[0x557516112120,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason 7)

Comment: Which laptop are you using?

Comment: HP Pavilion 15-n259tx